# Select statement without subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables (simplified example)

1 Config:

```
ConfigId|Settings
```

2 ReplacesConfig:

```
ConfigId|ReplaceWithConfigId
```

So lets say I got three rows in Config (ConfigId 1,2,3) and two rows in ReplacesConfig like this

```
1|2
2|3
```

This means that all config with Id 1 will be replaced with configId 2. But we also have one record that replaces all configId 2 with configId 3. So this means when I want to read the settings from ConfigId 1 I should get the settings from ConfigId 3. It could be more then two leves, so need a way which support this.

The select statement must be supported in a indexed view, so cannot use subqueries.

Comment: It seems like you know exactly what you want. So what is the problem?

Comment: I need to make an select statement, where i get all ids from the config table and the settings based on the replacesconfig table. Like this example i  should get ids 1,2,3, but all of them have the settings from condigid 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in an Indexed View because you need to use a recursive CTE to do this.